# printf(): When is %n written?

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  printf("hello%n%d\n", &i, i);
}
```

Why does it print `hello0` and not `hello5`?

Comment: Why it should print 5?? your integer value is 0 and that is what you are referring inside

Comment: Arguments in printf will be performed from Right to left. Based on compiler too.

Comment: Well, the %n specifier should write the amount of bytes written so far into the integer i, so i should contain the value 5 (because "hello" contains 5 characters)

Comment: The problem may seem obvious to anyone who's ever thought about functions and argument passing and reference semantics, but it seems like a perfectly reasonable question for someone who has not previously experienced this.

Answer (score 6):

When you call a function, the function arguments are *copied* into the scope of the called function. Since `i` is `0`, the value `0` is copied into the scope of `printf` and used to print in the `%d` conversion.

Additionally, the value `&i` is copied into the scope of the function, and the function uses that value to populate the variable at that address with the number of output bytes so far. So after your function call returns, you can inspect `i` to find that value.

The fact that you used the same variable to both produce a value for the `%d` argument and to produce an address for the `%n` argument is pure coincidence. In fact, the last `i` argument is really a bit misleading, since it is not the identity of `i` that matters here, but only its *value*. You might as well have put a literal `0` there. (Technically, the expression `i` undergoes "lvalue conversion", which is just a fancy way of saying that you don't care about the variable, only the value.)

Comment: Ah damn it, i missed that. Thanks. So %n is written instantly when printf parses the format string?

Comment: @delta242: No, or kind of. If by "immediately" you mean "during parsing". It is written once you reach that part of the output string. In your case, it should write the value 5 or so. You can check by printing the original `i` later on. The string isn't so much "parsed" as it is "processed", it's a simple left-to-right single-pass process.

Comment: Yeah I know, afterwards the variable i contains the value 5. I just need the "feature", that i gets written when the format string is parsed.

Comment: @delta242: Do you mean you want to print the running count *in the same* printf invocation? I'm not sure if that's possible... You would need another dereferencing conversion specifier, and I don't think there is one. (Though there are probably vendor extensions.)

Comment: I need it for exploiting format strings, it's for a course at university.

Comment: @delta242: Ah :-) Undoubtedly you'll find countless online resources that discuss that sort of stuff. There are many variations on this general idea, it shouldn't be hard to find examples.

Answer (score 1):

%n is not written. It means "nothing printed."

[From the fine manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
Nothing printed.
The corresponding argument must be a pointer to a signed int.
The number of characters written so far is stored in the pointed location.
```

In other words, after printf returns, `i` will contain the value 5. But not until printf returns - that is why you're seeing 0 instead of 5.

Comment: `i` will contain 5 when `printf` writes 5 to the address it was passed, which is before `printf` returns, so that is not the reason that “0” is printed rather than “5”. The reason “0” is printed is because 0 is the result of evaluating the argument `i` while preparing to call `printf`.